# How can I add the main page to the menu using pdo tools (website on ModX Revo)?

Tags: pdo, modx-revolution

I have a Modx Revo [website](http://like.alexanz3.beget.tech/vostochnaya-medicina) that contains several template sites. There is a menu that shows all the child elements of the main page (number 21). I want it to show the main page as well, but  &displayStart=`21` doesnt work. There is some error occuring and all the menu elements disappar. Can anyone help me?

```
[[pdoMenu?
    &displayStart=`21`                  
    &parents=`21`
    &level=`1`
]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is small error, displayStart is just a boolean flag, so all you need is the next:

```
&displayStart=`1`
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped) sorry for the delay